# .htaccess to expressjs routes

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

I'm in the process of moving to a nodejs express server from apache2. In this process, I now need to convert a .htaccess to expressjs routes, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Remove .html from urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# Is it a file? serve it, is it not a file? serve index.html
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

So basically, it serves all files to the browser. And if the requested path is not a file, it serves index.html. What would these look like in expressjs routes?

Currently, routes are like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html',{root: path.join(__dirname, './public')});
});

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [expressjs static method](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static) with default settings then you don't need to add anything else because this rules are already applied. For more information see [Serving static files in Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Also in order to server files without the html extension you need to following middleware.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function(req, res, next){
  var file = path.join(path.join(__dirname, './public'), req.path + '.html';

  fs.exist(file), function(exist){
      if(!exist) return next();

      res.sendFile(file);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I can get the routes that need to be index.html, to work,but not if i load sth like `localhost/ex`, which is supposed to serve `ex.html`, if it exists.

Comment: Isn't `fs.exist` deprecated, though? Got it working with `fs.access`.

Comment: Yes @rando-hinn fs.exist is deprecated. I didn't see the deprecation message just in front of my eyes. Sorry for that. I'm glad you get the idea.